# Clean architecture cascaded deletion of resources

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, architecture, clean-architecture

Currently, I have been trying to convert a codebase using "clean architecture" to try to separate many things, create better defined interfaces, and make code more easily testable.

Right now, we have resources which are related in a hierarchical manner. We can think of this as something like:

```
A
|-B
| |
| C
|
|-D
  |-F
  |-G
    |-H
    |-I
```

This is a very rough example and meant more to show than a description of precisely what I am working with.

In a case like this, I might have some "UseCase" where I want to "delete A". In our case, when we delete a type in this hierarchy we want to remove all associated data including data of child type. This is where I am not sure how to approach things exactly. There are a few approaches I have considered and am looking for better options.

The first would be to have a "UseCase" which has all this functionality (delete for all types) and can therefore reference itself to call other deletion methods. I really didn't like this as it seems to me to violate the "open/closed principle" and seems like it would be very hard to maintain.

The second approach was to have the "UseCase" "DeleteA" depend on "DeleteB" and "DeleteD" (for example). "DeleteA" would then have dependencies of "DeleteA & DeleteB & DeleteD". This seems like it makes it difficult to test since now it actually depends on interfaces of every child type "Delete" "UseCase".

I am struggling with how this should be approached. I have considered a service locator pattern which I also don't really like much. It seems like it makes dependencies unclear and they will only get resolved at runtime (no compile time check).

Any suggestions are welcome. I have found it difficult to find information on cases like this. Examples I have found seem to be fairly isolated to something like "DoSomethingWithX" where the result doesn't cascade across many types.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the resources you have are Entities, which the Use Case / application logic layer knows about.  I know a bit about [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) but not enough to know if any what what I am about to say violates any of it's specific rules.

How have you approached the entities?  Are they "dumb" like DTO's or do they have some smarts?  E.g. does an entity know who's it's immediate children are?  E.g. in your example D would know about F and G.

Options that come to mind:

**Dumb Entities** - If your entities have zero smarts, the App-Logic is forced to compensate by fetching all of the entities that might be related, and then manage their deletion.  Pros/cons:

- The deletion logic / smarts is all cleanly kept in the one layer (app logic layer - ignoring all the underpinning CRUD code which should be in it's appropriate layers).
- Performance may vary, and will be partially dictated by how efficiently you can fetch the tree of entities and process them.
- The entities can remain super dumb.  (Maybe too dumb?)
- The logic can perform whatever actions it needs to, to ensure entities can be safely deleted.  E.g. ensure other parts of the logic aren't trying to change the state of anything slated for deletion; ensure the deletion conforms with [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

**"I know my immediate Children" Entities** - If entities have very limited smarts: they know who their immediate children are, but not much else.  This would allow recursion.  The logic layers can do a loop, asking the first entity: 'hey, got any children'?  If true, those are fetched, added to a flat list of entities, and asked the same question until you get nothing but falses, and exit the loop.  Then the logic can delete all the entities on the flat list.  Pros/cons:

- The deletion logic / smarts is all cleanly kept in the one spot (app logic layer - ignoring all the underpinning CRUD code which should be in it's appropriate layers).
- Performance might suffer for larger entities trees, the more recursions you have to do.
- Assumes the entity tree is not altered part way through by something external tot he logic (e.g. child added to an entity that is not deleted yet - but just told the logic it had no children).  I guess you could look into some flag system so that the logic didn't violate itself.  There might be design patterns for that specific problem but I can't think of any off the top of my head or from a quick search.
- The entities can remain relatively dumb, but still have some basic useful methods.  Make sure you establish clear and consistent design rules on what is both "dumb" enough, and useful enough, to be added to the entities without bloating them and accidentally turning them into logic (un-clean architecture).

Deletion mechanisms should be able to handle various types as long as they implement a given interface e.g. IDeletable.

**In closing**, have a think about which approach is best for your situation: recursion-based (2nd option) or set-based (first option) where you build up a list of everything and then delete.  Think about what runtime assumptions are being made (can anything act on the entities you're about to delete), and balance runtime needs with design-time ones.

Don't forget you can "soft" delete stuff.  E.g. recursively set a flag, do a last minute check before doing a set-based deletion of all the soft-deleted items in-scope.

**Update RE Soft Delete / OP Comment**

Well, if you have an entity that just represents a physical record elsewhere (row in DB, file, etc), you can soft-delete the entity, and use that as a signal to the data access/file system code to go ahead and perform the actual delete.

The soft delete could be a bool, or you could define a flag that had more complex status, like `Normal`, `MarkedForDeletion`, `DeletionInProgress`, `Deleted` or whatever.

Comment: As a note, soft delete isn't necessarily an option for all things. In my case, actually some of these are not in databases and are actually binary files containing data which can be GB+ in size. This is actually one of the reasons deletion of associated resources is necessary in our case.

Reviewing your whole response and considering it. I will mark it if I don't have any further questions. I really appreciate the response 

Answer (score 0):

I guess with "delete" you mean the deletion in the persistence layer. If so the cascade deletion should be placed there and not in the use case.

You might have a CMS system where users can create pages for the web. These pages contain sections, images, may have attachments and so on. The use case "delete page" might do some validation logic before it asks the repository to delete the page, but then the repository is responsible for the deletion. And what the repository does is highly dependent on the type of storage you use. E.g. if the "page" is your aggregation root and the repository uses a document oriented nosql db it just removes the document and all included things like images, attachments ... are gone. If the persistence layer uses a relational database it might either remove rows from different tables or it also does only remove the page row and the cascading delete configuration of the db does the rest.

Thus I think it should be placed in persistence layer.

**EDIT**

> For my case, data is not necessarily stored only in a DB but also via different storage media (like binary files on some file storage for example).
>
> ....
>
> What you are suggesting seems that it would require repositories referencing other repositories. Is this what you mean?

The `UserRepo` could call delete on the `DocumentRepository`, but you can also inverse the dependency with an interface, e.g. a `UserChangedHandler` that has a method `onUserDeleted()`.

```
 +------------+        +--------------------+
 | DBUserRepo | -----> | UserChangedHandler |
 +------------+        +--------------------+
                                 ^
                                 |
               +-----------------+--------------+ 
               |                                |
 +------------------------+        +---------------------+ 
 | FileDocumentRepository |        | RestImageRepository |
 +------------------------+        +---------------------+
```

As you can see the `ChangeHandler` can be implemented by any other repository. It might delete `Document`s that are stored on the local file system and `Image`s that are stored on a remote server.

Either the repositories implement `UserChangeHandler` or you create an adapter to separate the handler logic from the repositories.

```
 +------------+        +--------------------+
 | DBUserRepo | -----> | UserChangedHandler |
 +------------+        +--------------------+
                                 ^
                                 |
                +---------------------------+        +------------------------+ 
                | DocumentUserChangeAdapter |  --->  | FileDocumentRepository |
                +---------------------------+        +------------------------+
```

In a distributed environment the `ChangeHandler` might also emit a message to a queue and other systems will asynchronously delete the other data.

> Your description also seems to mean that the "User Repo" would be aware of the entire hierarchy of data (User -> SomeData -> SomeOtherData) and so whenever anything changes in the hierarchy, it would effect the "User Repo".

As I tried to show above it doesn't necessarily mean that the `UserRepo` implementation is aware of all other data structures and persistence types. The persistence management must not reside on the same server nor run within the same process.

It's up to you how you structure your system. There are many different ways to solve it which depend on functional and non-functional requirements.

PS: You **tagged** your question with **typescript** so you might want to define the `UserChangeHandler` like this

```
export type UserChangeHandler = (userId : string) => void;
```

or return a `Promise<void>` if the change handler should support async.

Comment: For my case, data is not necessarily stored only in a DB but also via different storage media (like binary files on some file storage for example). There are other repositories which handle the access/management of these different types of data. What you are suggesting seems that it would require repositories referencing other repositories. Is this what you mean?  For example, if I had "user" and "document". The "User Repo" would reference the "Doc Repo" so that it could tell "Doc Repo" to manage the deletion?  Your description seems to assume all data is in one place.

Comment: Your description also seems to mean that the "User Repo" would be aware of the entire hierarchy of data (User -> SomeData -> SomeOtherData) and so whenever anything changes in the hierarchy, it would effect the "User Repo".

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean that the `UserRepo` implementation is aware of all other data structures. The `UserRepo` can call delete on other repositories which also delegate. You can even reverse the depenceny to other repositories by using an interface like `UserDeletionEventHandler` or something named better.